# React Native firebase Authentication handling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I am trying to create a simple Auth flow in my Expo application.

[I've reacreated my project here so you can see what I am doing](https://snack.expo.io/@allanaraujo/budget)

Right now what happens in my app is I can register a user using Firebase authtentication, but can't navigate to the authenticated flows. Nothing happens after I click register, but I can see the user in firebase.

I have been reading the React Navigaion docs and tried implementing something similar to what they do for the [Auth flow](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow) there, but have not had any success.

I think the issue has to do with how I am getting the token in App.js and my use of useEffect

App.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import * as eva from '@eva-design/eva';
import { Provider as AuthProvider } from './src/context/AuthContext';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { ApplicationProvider } from '@ui-kitten/components';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import LandingScreen from './src/screens/LandingScreen';
import RegisterScreen from './src/screens/RegisterScreen';
import LoginScreen from './src/screens/LoginScreen';
import HomeScreen from './src/screens/HomeScreen';
import DetailScreen from './src/screens/DetailScreen';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

/*eslint-disable */
export default function App() {
  let token;
  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch the token from storage then navigate to our appropriate place
    const localSignin = async () => {
      try {
        token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');
      } catch (e) {
        // Restoring token failed
      }
    };
    console.log(token);
    localSignin();
  }, []);

  return (
    <ApplicationProvider {...eva} theme={eva.light}>
      <AuthProvider>
        <NavigationContainer>
          {token ? (
            <>
              <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
                <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
                <Drawer.Screen name="Details" component={DetailScreen} />
              </Drawer.Navigator>
            </>
          ) : (
            <>
              <Stack.Navigator>
                <Stack.Screen name="Landing" component={LandingScreen} />
                <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} />
                <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
              </Stack.Navigator>
            </>
          )}
        </NavigationContainer>
      </AuthProvider>
    </ApplicationProvider>
  );
}
```

Should I be using my AuthContext here somewhere? I am very new to react development so I am sorry if this is somewhat unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Your "token" is manipulated asynchronously, so it should be a state variable so your component may re-render when it got changed. To achieve that, you should replace your token declaration with

```
const [token, setToken] = React.useState(undefined);
```

After that, when you want to change your token, instead of reassigning to the token variable, call setToken with the desired value. Like this:

```
setToken(await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken'));
```

The final code should look like this

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import * as eva from '@eva-design/eva';
import { Provider as AuthProvider } from './src/context/AuthContext';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { ApplicationProvider } from '@ui-kitten/components';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import LandingScreen from './src/screens/LandingScreen';
import RegisterScreen from './src/screens/RegisterScreen';
import LoginScreen from './src/screens/LoginScreen';
import HomeScreen from './src/screens/HomeScreen';
import DetailScreen from './src/screens/DetailScreen';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

/*eslint-disable */
export default function App() {
  const [token, setToken] = React.useState(undefined);
  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch the token from storage then navigate to our appropriate place
    const localSignin = async () => {
      try {
        setToken(await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken'));
      } catch (e) {
        // Restoring token failed
      }
    };
    console.log(token);
    localSignin();
  }, []);

  return (
    <ApplicationProvider {...eva} theme={eva.light}>
      <AuthProvider>
        <NavigationContainer>
          {token ? (
            <>
              <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
                <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
                <Drawer.Screen name="Details" component={DetailScreen} />
              </Drawer.Navigator>
            </>
          ) : (
            <>
              <Stack.Navigator>
                <Stack.Screen name="Landing" component={LandingScreen} />
                <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} />
                <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
              </Stack.Navigator>
            </>
          )}
        </NavigationContainer>
      </AuthProvider>
    </ApplicationProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. This isn't doing anything. Did you by chance see the link to the project? I have token as a part of my AuthContext.js and wonder if I should be using the token there instead of the way you mentioned here? the console.log here in use effect is showing token as undefined.

Comment: And Im wording if I should be using that AuthContext here

Comment: In your AuthContext, you are storing the value of response.user.getIdToken(). That method returns a Promise<string>, then you should "await" it. I'm gonna edit the answer as soon as i finish debugging it

Comment: About using the AuthContext inside the App.js, to achieve that you can use your AuthContext as a ContextConsumer, or split your App.js in two components (you cannot use the useContext hook inside your app because it is not surrounded by you Provider)

Comment: haha ok I'm going to need to do some more reading on this because I'm not sure what you mean by breaking up App.js into two components. To me, that seems like the better way to handle this?

Comment: Please let me know what you get when you debug as well. Much appreciate